# Shift bit-wise operation

Tags: c, if-statement, integer, bitwise-operators, shift

I'm learning c programming and now struggling with the bit-wise operation. Say if I want to shift short n >> by 4 and << by 10, and use the short result as the condition of a loop. i.e `if (result==1) {//do something}` do I need to declare another two variables, i.e. `short right= n>>4; short left=...` or is there a more proper way of writing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need additional variables unless you intend to use the result of the shifts more than once.

Shifting right by 4 and then left by 10 is not the same as just shifting left by 6, so you have to do separate shifts if you want the side effect of shifting past the end of the right side to zero out some of the right-hand bits, eg:

```
short n = ...;
if (((n >> 4) << 10) == 1) {
    //do something
}
```

Let's say you start with `0xFFFF` (`1111111111111111`).  Shifting right by 4 produces `0x0FFF` (`0000111111111111`), then shifting that left by 10 produces `0xFC00` (`1111110000000000`).

On the other hand, if you just shift left by 6:

```
short n = ...;
if ((n << 6) == 1) {
    //do something
}
```

`0xFFFF` becomes `0xFFC0` (`1111111111000000`) instead.  Clearly not the same value.

So you have to be careful with your shifts.

BTW, shifting by these particular values will never produce a result of 1.

Comment: As you say, it is clearly not the same. I would give OP the benefit of the doubt that the _side effect_ is indeed what he wants.

Comment: Thanks but yes I meant to get rid of some of the bits by shifting. So if I declare a `short n`, then <<7, and then >>6, I will get to keep the middle 8-10 bits, right?

Comment: If your goal is to extract specific bits, or mask out specific bits, you should be using the `&` and `^` operators for that instead. If you want the extracted bits as an integer, use `>>` to shift them enough bits to put them into the right-most side. For example: `(n & 0x700) >> 8` (`0x700` = bits 8, 9, and 10).

Comment: @RemyLebeau could you elaborate on 'never produce a result of 1'? if the number is 0001 000 000 000 000, and I >>12, would the result equal to 1?

Comment: @RemyLebeau ah yes my goal is to extract specific bits! so I should use & ^? Sorry not getting the idea here..

Comment: @stillAFanOfTheSimpsons Yes `0x1000 >> 12` equals 1.  But in your original example, shifting by `<< 10` leaves the right-hand 10 bits set to 0, which omits 1 as a possible result.